# Rollup Error: 'isValidElementType' is not exported by node_modules/react-is/index.js

Tags: reactjs, rollup, styled-components

I'm building a bundle with rollUp using styled-components.

My rollup.config.js looks like:

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  external: [
    'react',
    'react-proptypes'
  ],
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      extensions: [ '.js', '.json', '.jsx' ]
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    })
  ]
}
```

And I'm receiving

```
[!] Error: 'isValidElementType' is not exported by node_modules/react-is/index.js
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module
node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.es.js (7:9)
5: import stream from 'stream';
6: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
7: import { isValidElementType } from 'react-is';
            ^
8: import hoistStatics from 'hoist-non-react-statics';
```

Checking on the node_modules itself react-is is a commonjs module as it can be checked out [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-is/npm/index.js) as well.

Shouldn't  the commonjs plugin take care of it since it is inside node_modules/** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I resolved this by using the `rollup-plugin-commonjs`

and defining the export manually in the rollup config as below

```
export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    postcss({
      modules: true
    }),
    url(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**',
      namedExports: {
        'node_modules/react-is/index.js': ['isValidElementType']
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

After this everything worked fine.

and for the info, my initial setup was done through https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/react-modern-library-boilerplate

Hope it works for you

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, though I had to use ['isValidElementType', 'isContextConsumer'] for my array.

Answer (score 17):

The fix above didn't work for me. However, adding `styled-components` to the `rollup.config.js` list of externals and globals worked for me.

```
    export default {
      ...
      external: ['styled-components'],
      ...
      globals: { 'styled-components': 'styled' },
    };
```

I'm using the typescript [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library) cli, which comes bundled with rollup.

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/930

Comment: Just to update, it looks like globals is now part of `output`. So it should now be:
`
...
external: ['styled-components']
...
output: {
  globals: { 'styled-components': 'styled' }
}`

Comment: Another update for `create-react-library` - as it's using (a fork of) microbundle passing `--external styled-components` through the command-line build command works

Answer (score 7):

Here is an updated answer for 2022.

I ran into this error using vitejs, which uses rollup for its production builds/bundling.

I have included a solution for rollup and vite projects.

---

**A note on old answers and documentation**

In docs and forums on the internet there are still a lot of old comments referring to `rollup-plugin-commonjs` and `namedExports`.

- The last release of `rollup-plugin-commonjs` was `v10.1.0` in 2019-08-27
- `rollup-plugin-commonjs` was renamed to `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` with `v11.0.0` in 2019-12-21
- `namedExports` was removed from `@rollup/plugin-commonjs@v13.0.0` in 2020-06-05

So anything that refers to `rollup-plugin-commonjs` or `namedExports` is **outdated** and not relevant to the current version of `rollup` or `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`.

---

#### Why we get this error

This error happens with a lot of React libs because they use dynamic `require(...)` statements to choose between dev and production source files.

I'm using `react` for this example, but it's the same idea in `react-dom` and `react-is`.

```
// node_modules/react/index.js

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.production.min.js');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.development.js');
}
```

When rollup processes this file it can't work out that the exports come from another file, so it rollup thinks the exports are empty, and that is why we get an error like `'useState' is not exported by 'node_modules/react/index.js'`.

---

#### Solutions

**Option 1: Make libraries external**

Use this option if you don't want to include the dependency inside your  bundle at all.

In this case, mark these libraries as `external`, meaning they won't be processed by rollup or included in the bundle.
This can also reduce the size of your bundle and avoid accidentally bundling these libraries multiple times.

Any libraries marked as external will need to be made available in the runtime environment (i.e. they're available on the page at runtime, or you have another build step that can resolve the externals and provide them to your library).

---

**Option 2: Use aliases to manually resolve the files**

Use this option if you your dependencies **should be** included inside your bundle - i.e. you want React to be included inside your library bundle.

1. Install [@rollup/plugin-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias)

```
$ npm install @rollup/plugin-alias --save-dev
```

2. Configure aliases in your `rollup.config.js`.

```js
// rollup.config.js
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import * as _path from 'path';

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

/*
Define any path here that triggers the "is not exported" error

This is not needed if the react libraries are marked as `externals` and excluded from the bundle.
This is only an needed because we **want** react to be included in the bundle.
*/
let pathReact = 'umd/react.production.min.js';
let pathReactDom = 'umd/react-dom.production.min.js';
let pathReactJsx = 'cjs/react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js';
if (!isProduction){
  pathReact = 'umd/react.development.js';
  pathReactDom = 'umd/react-dom.development.js';
  pathReactJsx = 'cjs/react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js';
}

module.exports = {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'output',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [
    alias({
      entries: [
        {
          find: /^react$/,
          replacement: require.resolve(_path.join('react', pathReact)),
        },
        {
          find: /^react-dom$/,
          replacement: require.resolve(_path.join('react-dom', pathReactDom)),
        },
        {
          /*
          2022-03-11
          https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6215#issuecomment-1064247764
          */
          find: /react\/jsx-runtime/,
          replacement: require.resolve(_path.join('react', pathReactJsx)),
        },
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

NOTE:

- This assumes you are using `NODE_ENV` environment variable to control production/development builds
- I'm aliasing to the `umd` react files; if you need to point to the `cjs` build then adjust the alias path as necessary

---

#### Vitejs version

Here is the equivalent configuration for a vitejs project:

```
// vite.config.ts
import * as _path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig((env) => {
  // mode: 'production' | 'development'
  const mode = env.mode;

  /**
   * Fix build messages/errors like: `'useState' is not exported by 'node_modules/react/index.js'`
   */
  let pathReact = "umd/react.production.min.js";
  let pathReactDom = "umd/react-dom.production.min.js";
  let pathReactJsx = "cjs/react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js";
  if (mode === "development") {
    pathReact = "umd/react.development.js";
    pathReactDom = "umd/react-dom.development.js";
    pathReactJsx = "cjs/react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js";
  }

  return {
    resolve: {
      alias: [
        // react alias fix
        {
          find: /^react$/,
          replacement: require.resolve(_path.join("react", pathReact)),
        },
        {
          find: /^react-dom$/,
          replacement: require.resolve(_path.join("react-dom", pathReactDom)),
        },
        {
          /*
          2022-03-11
          https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6215#issuecomment-1064247764
          */
          find: /react\/jsx-runtime/,
          replacement: require.resolve(_path.join("react", pathReactJsx)),
        },
        // End react alias fix
      ],
    },
    plugins: [react()],
  };
});
```

Comment: TypeError: __require.resolve is not a function

Answer (score 6):

The solution posted by FrostyDog worked for me so +1 for that, HOWEVER...

I immediately got the same error when trying to import hooks from `react`, I could follow the above solution and do

```
    export default {
      ...
      external: ['styled-components', 'react'],
      ...
    };
```

in `rollup.config.js` but **I wanted a solution that handled this for all libraries**, so this wasn't a recurring issue in the future.

So did this instead...

```
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
...
export default {
    ...
    plugins: [
        external({
            includeDependencies: true
        }),
        ...
    ]
};
```

solved it for me and everyone adding to the project after.

Comment: This solves my problem(2023)

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem when build:

```
    Error: 'typeOf' is not exported by ../../node_modules/react-is/index.js, imported by ../../node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.esm.js
1: import { typeOf as e, isElement as t, isValidElementType as n } from "react-is";
```

you can use this code in rollup commonjs config:

```
plugins: [
...
...
...    
commonjs({
      ignoreGlobal: true,
      include: /\/node_modules\//,
      namedExports: {
        react: Object.keys(require("react")),
        "react-is": Object.keys(require("react-is")),
      },
    }),
...
]
```

this code resolves react-is import error when building your project.
reference for read more:
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3256#issuecomment-694144760

Answer (score 1):

```
export default {
    ...
    external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'styled-components'],
    globals: { 'styled-components': 'styled' },
    plugins: [
        external({
            includeDependencies: true
        }),
        ...
    ]
};
```