# 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve' can't work with `useState` of react, how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup

In a typescript project, I use `typescript` + `rollup` + `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` + React's `useState` together, but when run `rollup -c`, it throws error:

```
1: import {useState} from "react";
           ^
2: 
Error: 'useState' is not exported by node_modules/react/index.js
```

My code is quite simple:

```
import {useState} from "react";

console.log(useState);
```

And the `rollup.config.js` is:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';

export default {
  input: 'index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: 'bundle.js',
      format: 'cjs',
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript(),
  ]
};
```

**package.json** is:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "demo": "rollup -c && node bundle.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "16.8.8",
    "rollup": "1.6.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "9.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "4.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "0.20.1",
    "typescript": "3.3.3333"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

If I remove `resolve()` from `rollup.config.js`, rollup will bundle it correctly. But I need to use `resolve()` in my real project.

Where is wrong and how to fix it?

PS: Complete code demo is here: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-react-rollup-use-state-demo

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but have you tried defining the export manually [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080893/rollup-error-isvalidelementtype-is-not-exported-by-node-modules-react-is-inde) to see if it works?

Comment: as a temporary fix you can import only `React` and use `React.useState`

Comment: uncertain about the dependencies here, but it looks like your `react` and `@types/react` are not in sync. Could it be it?

Comment: @Tholle You're right, I have to define a `namedExports` for `useState`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the answer link provided by @Tholle, the problem is rollup-plugin-commonjs is not able to find the `setState` export from react, since react declare it like:

```
const React = {
    setState
}
module.exports = React
```

rollup-plugin-commonjs can't handle such form of exports, so we have to define some named exports in rollup.config.js, like:

```
plugins: [
   'react': ['useState']
]
```

Comment: `plugins: [ 'react': ['useState'] ]`doesn't work, it's not even valid JS syntax

Answer (score 0):

This setup configuration works for me

```
// rollup config 
plugins: [
   commonjs({
      // ... other commonjs config options
      namedExports: {
         // https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs#custom-named-exports
         'node_modules/react/index.js': ['useState', 'useRef', 'useEffect'],
       },
     }),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out I needed to add peerDependencies in my package.json:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
```